# When not to use a private field?

Tags: c#

When should it be considered dangerous to use a **private** field all over the place in the methods of your class?  I mostly just create the variable and set it to a default value like null.  Then in my methods reference it and set it to an instance of that object type from the methods.

I don't know if my question makes sense but let me know if it doesn't and I'll clarify.

Comment: Please give an example.  It's not at all unusual to have a private field that used frequently in a class.  It's not clear what you mean, "I mostly just create the variable and set it to a default value like null."  Ideally, fields are initialized to a valid value in the constructor, so the class invariant always holds.

Comment: Are you asking if its okay to set private fields inside of a function?

Comment: I'm talking about private fields you declare at the top of your class that is scoped to that class and that class only..typical private fields of a class, and these fields are being referenced from various methods inside that class.  There are situations where you shouldn't be using a lot of class scoped fields like this because it can lead to conflicting changes and methods will be referencing fields with unstable values since other methods could change it before it gets to another.

Comment: Fields are not always initialized via constructor.  You could let the .NET Framework initialize them to their default type values (bool is false, etc.) and then your methods could actually set the values.  It all depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 4):

If you only need the member inside a single call to a method then prefer to make it a local variable instead of a member. The more local your variables, the easier it is to understand the program.

If it's necessary to use the same object across multiple calls, you could consider if the member could be made readonly and set in the constructor.

Comment: what if you don't set it in the constructor...meaning one of the method's in your class has the logic to set it and you want to leave it up to the methods to set.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, if you *are* going to use a field all over in your class it *should* be private, but that can often be a code smell signalling state that is being managed in many places.

Not bad in itself, but the complexity can grow quickly in that case.

Comment: yea I'm not talking about globals...private fields only.

Comment: @coffeeaddict, But it sounds like you're using private fields where a local variable would do just as well. That's definitely a code smell... a bad one.

Comment: It depends, you're going to have a few here and there at the top of your class that can be reused...not all variables are local but yest most are.  I find 2-3 fields I can reuse at the top of my class that for example represents a singleton that's set by the constructor and then I reuse that field across methods that need it because that singleton is not going to change...it's a singleton.  A few methods in my class need it...no big deal.  No reason to pass it through the params of every method that needs it.

Comment: so  you're saying you never have private fields at the top of your class that are used inside methods?  Then what do you do pass everything via method params only and use private fields ONLY for setting properties in which case you wouldn't need the private fields anyway with automatic properties.  Then you're saying if you use automatic properties you're not going to have at least a couple fields at the top that can be reusable inside a few methods such as a reference to a singleton that is safe to use across all methods?

Answer (score 0):

If the variable holds sensitive Data you should be aware that it is still accessible from outside with reflection.

Otherwise if you can avoid a private field you shouldn't use one. If you can't, there's nothing wrong with a local field if it is used correctly.

This is a bad idea:

```
public class Calculator()
{
    private int result;

    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        result = a + b;
        return result;
    }
}
```

because you can get a race condition if two threads call the Add() method at the same time and after the first thread sets the result the context is switched to the second thread wich sets the result and both calls return the value from the second one.

Those errors are hard to debug because they are completely random.

Comment: Yea but if I use all locals, I'll have to recreate instances of an object all over when that object can be reused.

Comment: Sure, but that was just a simple example for a race condition. As I wrote: using local fields is ok if it makes sense. And reusing an object is a good reason to use a local field.